# Fix overfull line by local settings of microtype expansion

Tags: line-breaking, microtype

The second line of the paragraphs has an overulll (6pt). I can't change the text and the hyphenation of the first two line (pri-vate and al-ready) would not help.

[image: Paragraph to fix overfull]

I try to change the microtype settings (I use the default ones) for this paragraph:

```
\SetExpansion
[ context = sloppy,
stretch = 30,
shrink = 60,
step
= 5 ]
{ encoding = {OT1,T1,TS1} }
{ }

{\microtypecontext{expansion=sloppy}%
You are horrified at our intending to do away with private
property.  But in your existing society, private property is
already done away with for nine-tenths of the population; its
existence for the few is solely due to its non-existence in the
hands of those nine-tenths.  You reproach us, therefore, with
intending to do away with a form of property, the necessary
condition for whose existence is the non-existence of any
property for the immense majority of society.
}
```

But I got the error (lualatex 0.80 and microtype v2.5a):

```
! Package microtype Error: microtype isn't set up for expansion contexts.
(microtype)                Ignoring `context' key on input line 701.
```

I don't understand what is going on. Someone can explain me the way to change the microtype parameters locally.

Any other advice on how to fix this overfull lines is wellcome.

Comment: Load `microtype` with the `copyfonts` option or move the `\SetExpansion` block to the preamble.

Comment: Moving `\SetExpansion` to the preamble works fine. I didn't understand the `copyfonts` option. Unfortunately, this is not helping to fix the `Overfull` box. Please make the comment an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to either move the `\SetExpansion` block to the preamble or load the `microtype` package with the `copyfonts` option.  The documentation says

> `copyfonts` will copy all fonts before setting them up. This allows protrusion and expansion with different parameters.  This options is also *undocumented* in the hope that we can always find out automatically whether it’s required.

That is to say, moving the `\SetExpansion` block to the preamble is the better practice, as it allows `microtype` to detect whether copying the fonts is necessary.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\SetExpansion
[ context = sloppy,
  stretch = 30,
  shrink = 60,
  step = 5 ]
{ encoding = {OT1,T1,TS1} }
{ }
\newcommand\text{You are horrified at our intending to do away with
  private property.  But in your existing society, private property is
  already done away with for nine-tenths of the population; its
  existence for the few is solely due to its non-existence in the hands
  of those nine-tenths.  You reproach us, therefore, with intending to
  do away with a form of property, the necessary condition for whose
  existence is the non-existence of any property for the immense
  majority of society.}
\begin{document}
\text

{\microtypecontext{expansion=sloppy}\text}
\end{document}
```

> [image]